# Como renderizar um html que veio da resposta de um json?

Tags: angularjs

Resposta do JSON:

```
post: {
   body: "<div>O meu html vem dessa forma</div>"
}
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra renderizar esse meu `post.body` na minha view. Existe alguma diretiva que faça isso pra mim???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com esse tipo de resposta no formato HTML seria necessário carregar no angular no [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) e usar a `tag` para o carregamento ***`ng-bind-html`*** (`angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);`).

***Exemplo minimo:***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
{
     $scope.result = '';        
     $scope.submit = function()
     {
         var post = {
            body: "<div>O meu <i>html</i> <b>vem</b> dessa forma</div>"
         }
         $scope.result = post.body;
       
     }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="result"></p>
  <a href="#" ng-click="submit();">Clique para carregar</a>
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

Answer (score 1):

Veja este exemplo no fiddle, será necessário um decode na variável body e um append no elemento que irá receber o html:
http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/gWcse/

Comment: saberia fazer isso só com o angular??? Não posso utilizar o jquery...

Answer (score 1):

Caso você ainda não tenha conseguido, vc pode usar [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)